# SceneKit: How to place a 3D object in order to fit the SCNView bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode, scnscene

I'm new to `SceneKit` and **3D objects**. I've been doing some research but I didn't find an answer to my question.

I need to display several 3D objects in an horizontal `UICollectionView`, one in each cell. I'd like them to be aligned and the same size so I'd like them to fit the parent view, aka the `SCNView`.

An image to picture the scenario:

[image: 3D objects, each in a SCNView, all the same size]

I'd like that the bounds of the 3D object visually matches the bounds of the SCNView. I want the 3D object to "fit" in the view, a bit like `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit`.

---

Here's my code so far:

```
let scene=SCNScene(named: file_name)
let node=scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: node_name, recursively: true)!
node.scale=SCNVector3Make(28, 28, 28)
node.position=SCNVector3Make(0, 0.05, -0.5)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
sceneview.scene=scene
```

Comment: "I don't know how to link the SCNView bounds and the SCNScene/SCNNode dimensions/position. "  I don't precisely understand your question.  Yet, your best bet is to position the node at the center of the scene.  And your node position does not appear feasible.

Comment: @ElTomato This is not very clear indeed. I'd like that visually the bounds of the 3D object matches the bounds of the SCNView. I want the 3D object to "fit" in the view, a bit like `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit`.

Comment: There is no such content-fit method to my knowledge.  I have never heard of an API that lets you draw the scene boundaries, either.

Comment: @ElTomato So even by scaling the object and changing its position there's no way to achieve that?

Comment: I managed to place them quite well. Although it's working on simulator, it's crashing on device. Seems like that several `SCNView` is too heavy.

Comment: Have you considered using a SpriteKit overlay scene?

Comment: No, I don't think I ever used a SpriteKit overlay scene.